# Trouble removing Wordpress submenus with long URL strings

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm running Wordpress multisite 4.3 and I'm trying to remove some submenus from the Appearance menu for my site editors. I've had success with removing the fly-out links to 'themes,' 'widgets,' 'menus' and 'customize' with the code below, by creating a new capability and keying off that:

```
$cap = 'no_see_menus';

function edit_admin_menus() {
    global $submenu;

    if(!current_user_can($cap)){

    remove_submenu_page('themes.php','themes.php');
    remove_submenu_page('themes.php','widgets.php');
    remove_submenu_page('themes.php','nav-menus.php');
    remove_submenu_page('themes.php','customize.php?return=%2Fic%2Fwp-admin%2Findex.php' );

    }
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'edit_admin_menus' );
```

The problem comes when I try to remove links to the header and background customization, both of which have strings that include ampersands. But even after replacing '&' with `&amp;` in the string, the function will not pick it up:

```
remove_submenu_page('themes.php','customize.php?return=%2Fic%2Fwp-admin%2Findex.php&amp;autofocus%5Bcontrol%5D=header_image' );  
remove_submenu_page('themes.php','customize.php?return=%2Fic%2Fwp-admin%2Findex.php&amp;autofocus%5Bcontrol%5D=background_image' );
```

So I'm stuck here. I greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can likely do it with css `display:none`. The trick will be using browser dev tools to determine if the submenus have unique enough id/class.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried that, and unfortunately, the menu items don't have unique classes or IDs. All of the links have a class of `hide-if-no-customize.`

Comment: Have you tried this: remove_submenu_page('themes.php','customize.php');

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish what I needed with what I'm sure is a super cludgy method. I had to create one function for part of the menus and another to get rid of the custom header and custom background menus. Here it is in all its ugliness.

```
// remove some menus and sub-menus for custom editor role

$cap = 'no_see_menus';
function edit_admin_menus() {
global $submenu;
    if(!current_user_can($cap)){
        remove_menu_page('tools.php'); // Remove the Tools menu
    remove_submenu_page('themes.php','themes.php');
        remove_submenu_page('themes.php','customize.php?return=%2Fic%2Fwp-admin%2Findex.php' );
        remove_submenu_page('themes.php','customize.php?return=%2Fic%2Fwp-admin%2Fwidgets.php');
        remove_submenu_page('themes.php','customize.php?return=%2Fic%2Fwp-admin%2Fnav-menus.php');
        }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'edit_admin_menus' );

// remove custom backgound and custom header menus and sub-menus for editor role

$cap = 'no_see_menus';
function remove_twentyeleven_options(){
    if(!current_user_can($cap)){
            remove_custom_background();
            remove_custom_image_header();
        }
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme','remove_twentyeleven_options', 100 );
```

If anyone has a more elegant way to achieve this, by all means post it here. Thanks for the suggestions.